# How to split the content of a folder into subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, shell, slurm

I would like to know if there is an easy way to automatically (programmatically, within a **bash** script) to split the content of a folder into subfolders with the parent folder.

I have a folder let's say with 580 files (of the same suffix), which I would like to split into six subfolders named e.g. `subfolder1`, `subfolder2`, etc. and put in each 100 files except the last which will contain the rest), or split evenly, if easier).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
subfolders=( subfolder{1..6} )
files=( *(N.) )
n=100
while (( $#files && $#subfolders )); do
  mkdir -p -- $subfolders[1] && mv -- $files[1,100] $subfolders[1]/
  subfolders[1]=() files[1,100]=()
done
```

You could also move them in a round-robin fashion with `zmv` (zsh's batch renamer):

```
autoload -Uz zmv
subfolders=( subfolder{1..6} )
mkdir -p -- $subfolders
(n=0; zmv '*(#q.)' '$subfolders[n++ % $#subfolders + 1]/$f')
```

Comment: What do I need to do in bash?